# Unable to CURL nginx kubernetes pod while it is running a loop command

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, curl

I have a nginx deployment in kubernetes that I would like to run commands from while it is being CURLed by another pod. It appears that while a nginx pod is executing a deployment command, it is unable to be CURLed.

For example: if there are two pods, `nginx-1` and `nginx-2`. `nginx-1` is repeatedly running CURLs to `nginx-2`, while `nginx-2` is repeatedly running it's own commands, the CURLs fail with `Connection Refused`.

Deployment Snippets:
Note: env `${TARGET_HTTP_ADDR} is declared in deployment.

- `nginx-1`:

  ```
   command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "--" ]
   args: [ "while sleep 30; do curl -v --head ${TARGET_HTTP_ADDR}; done"]
  ```
- `nginx-2`:

  ```
   command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "--" ]
   args: [ "while true; do echo hello; sleep 10; done" ]
  ```

Error resp:

```
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x55ad4f13df50)
* connect to <IP> port 8080 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to nginx-2 80: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
* curl: (7) Failed to connect to nginx-2 port 80: Connection refused
```

Why does this occur and is there any way around this? It appears that the deployment command does not allow the pod to respond to CURLs.

If the loop was run within a shell of `nginx-2`, the CURLs from `nginx-1` work.

Answer (score 1):

With 'command' and 'args' you are overwriting the usual docker entrypoint. So in your pods there is no more nginx process running and so nothing can answer to the cURL.
Maybe you should have two container in one pod. The first container with your nginx, the second one just a busybox image where you are doing the curl.

Comment: Thanks for your first answer. I would suggest a small improvement in the wording:

"there is no more nginx process"

would be better written as:

"nginx process has exited"